# Thermal aware scheduler in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler

Currently i'm working on making a temperature aware version of linux for my university project. Right now I have to create a temperature aware scheduler which could take into account processor temperature and perform some scheduling. Is there any generalized way to get the temperature of the processor cores or can I integrate the coretemp driver with the linux kernel in any way ( I didn't find a way to do so on the internet ).

Comment: Do you mean per core temperature? Also depends on if you want to do this in user space or kernel space.

Comment: yes the requirements are to try and make it for multi-core systems and to make the scheduler in the kernel if that is what you mean ( sorry I'm pretty new to this area of computing )

Comment: I think your project can be done without modifying the kernel, if you're willing to sacrifice direct process and IO scheduling for setting nice value and setting max processor frequency. You might be interested to look at cpufreqd and modifying that to take temperature into account.

Comment: How is your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lm-sensors simply uses some device files exported by the kernel for CPU temperature, you can just read whatever these device files have as backing variables in the kernel to get the temperature information. In terms of a scheduler I would not write one from scratch and would start with the kernels CFS implementation and in your case modify the load balancer check to include temperature (currently it uses a metric that is the calculated cost of moving a task from one core to another in terms of cache issues, etc... I'm not sure if you want to keep this or not).

Comment: Thanks, i will look into the `load_balance()` method more closely, and I agree with you about using some variables which actually store the values of the temperature instead of lm-sensors as that needs to be installed separately. However I was unable to find it so far except for the fact that some thermal files are located under `/sys/class/thermal/`

Comment: check `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.#/temp1_input` I forget where in the kernel the sysfs backing for this is and I don't have the code handy to check.

Comment: yes I can get the values from there , this is much better than using a separate application thanks! In case you find out where in the kernel the sysfs backing for this is please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature control is very difficult.  The difficulty is with [thermal capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) and conductance.  It is quite easy to read a temperature.  How you control it will depend on the system model.  A [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) or some higher order filter will be helpful.  You don't know,

1. Sources of heat.
2. Distance from sensors.
3. Number of sensors.
4. Control elements, like a fan.

If you only measure at the `CPU` itself, the hard drive could have over heated 10 minutes ago, but the heat is only arriving at the CPU now.  Throttling the `CPU` at this instance is not going to help.  Only by getting a good **thermal model** of the system can you control the heat.  Yet, you say you don't really know anything about the system?  I don't see how a scheduler by itself can do this.

I have worked on mobile **freezer** application where operators would load pallets of *ice cream*, etc from a freezer to a truck.  Very small distances between sensors and control elements can create havoc with a control system.  Also, you want your ambient temperature to be read instantly if possible.  There is a lot of `lag` in temperature control.  A small distance could delay a reading by 5-15 minutes (ie, it take 5-15 minutes for heat to transfer 1cm).

I don't see the utility of what you are proposing.  If you want this for a PC, then video cards, hard drives, power supplies, sound cards, etc. can create as much heat as the CPU.  You can not generically model a PC; maybe you could with an Apple product.  I don't think you will have a lot of success, but you will learn a lot from trying!